# Spring boot Error creating bean with name 'canalRessource' defined in file Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, spring-mvc

When i run my java app this error occurs  : " Error creating bean with name 'canalRessource' defined in file [C:\project\bo\target\classes\fcb\inetum\bo\CanalRessource.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0;"

this my **pom.xml** :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.13</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>fcb.inetum</groupId>
    <artifactId>bo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>backoffice</name>
    <description>backoffice app</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

this is my main app code:

```
package fcb.inetum.bo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class BackofficeApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(BackofficeApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

this my **canalressource.java** :

```
package fcb.inetum.bo;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.DeleteMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PutMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import fcb.inetum.bo.model.canal;
import fcb.inetum.bo.service.canalService;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/canal")
public class CanalRessource {
    private final canalService canalService;

    public CanalRessource(canalService canalService) {

        this.canalService = canalService;
    }

    @GetMapping("/all")
    public ResponseEntity<List<canal>> getAllCanal() {
        List<canal> canals = canalService.FindAllCanal();
        return new ResponseEntity<>(canals, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @GetMapping("/find/{canal_codi}")
    public ResponseEntity<canal> getCanalById(@PathVariable("canal_codi") String canal_codi) {
        canal canal = canalService.findCanalBycanal_codi(canal_codi);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(canal, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

@PostMapping("/add")
public ResponseEntity<canal>   AddCanal(@RequestBody canal canal)   {
    canal newcanal =canalService.AddCanal(canal);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(canal, HttpStatus.CREATED);
}


@PutMapping("/update")
public ResponseEntity<canal>   UpdateCanal(@RequestBody canal canal)   {
    canal newcanal =canalService.UpdateCanal(canal);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(canal, HttpStatus.OK);
}


@DeleteMapping("/delete/{canal_codi}")
public ResponseEntity<?> DeleteCanal(@PathVariable("canal_codi") String canal_codi) {
canalService.DeleteCanal(canal_codi);
    return new ResponseEntity<>( HttpStatus.OK);
}
}
```

this is my **canal.java**

```
package fcb.inetum.bo.model;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.*;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name="canal")
public class canal implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private String codi_canal;
    private String nom;
    private int id_banc;
    private String auto_revisio;
    private Date data_alta;
    private Date data_modificacio;
    private Date data_baixa;
    private String id_extern;
    private String actiu;
    private String email_responsable;
    private String usr_alta;
    private String usr_modificacio;
    private String usr_baixa;
    private String canal_pci;
    private String password;
    private String url_retorn;
    private int timeout_3d;
    private String reintent_3d_error;
    private String url_notificacio;

    public canal() {
    }

    public canal(String codi_canal, String nom, int id_banc, String auto_revisio, Date data_alta, Date data_modificacio,
            Date data_baixa, String id_extern, String actiu, String email_responsable, String usr_alta,
            String usr_modificacio, String usr_baixa, String canal_pci, String password, String url_retorn,
            int timeout_3d, String reintent_3d_error, String url_notificacio) {

        this.codi_canal = codi_canal;
        this.nom = nom;
        this.id_banc = id_banc;
        this.auto_revisio = auto_revisio;
        this.data_alta = data_alta;
        this.data_modificacio = data_modificacio;
        this.data_baixa = data_baixa;
        this.id_extern = id_extern;
        this.actiu = actiu;
        this.email_responsable = email_responsable;
        this.usr_alta = usr_alta;
        this.usr_modificacio = usr_modificacio;
        this.usr_baixa = usr_baixa;
        this.canal_pci = canal_pci;
        this.password = password;
        this.url_retorn = url_retorn;
        this.timeout_3d = timeout_3d;
        this.reintent_3d_error = reintent_3d_error;
        this.url_notificacio = url_notificacio;
    }

    public String getCodi_canal() {
        return codi_canal;
    }

    public void setCodi_canal(String codi_canal) {
        this.codi_canal = codi_canal;
    }

    public String getNom() {
        return nom;
    }

    public void setNom(String nom) {
        this.nom = nom;
    }

    public int getId_banc() {
        return id_banc;
    }

    public void setId_banc(int id_banc) {
        this.id_banc = id_banc;
    }

    public String getAuto_revisio() {
        return auto_revisio;
    }

    public void setAuto_revisio(String auto_revisio) {
        this.auto_revisio = auto_revisio;
    }

    public Date getData_alta() {
        return data_alta;
    }

    public void setData_alta(Date data_alta) {
        this.data_alta = data_alta;
    }

    public Date getData_modificacio() {
        return data_modificacio;
    }

    public void setData_modificacio(Date data_modificacio) {
        this.data_modificacio = data_modificacio;
    }

    public Date getData_baixa() {
        return data_baixa;
    }

    public void setData_baixa(Date data_baixa) {
        this.data_baixa = data_baixa;
    }

    public String getId_extern() {
        return id_extern;
    }

    public void setId_extern(String id_extern) {
        this.id_extern = id_extern;
    }

    public String getActiu() {
        return actiu;
    }

    public void setActiu(String actiu) {
        this.actiu = actiu;
    }

    public String getEmail_responsable() {
        return email_responsable;
    }

    public void setEmail_responsable(String email_responsable) {
        this.email_responsable = email_responsable;
    }

    public String getUsr_alta() {
        return usr_alta;
    }

    public void setUsr_alta(String usr_alta) {
        this.usr_alta = usr_alta;
    }

    public String getUsr_modificacio() {
        return usr_modificacio;
    }

    public void setUsr_modificacio(String usr_modificacio) {
        this.usr_modificacio = usr_modificacio;
    }

    public String getUsr_baixa() {
        return usr_baixa;
    }

    public void setUsr_baixa(String usr_baixa) {
        this.usr_baixa = usr_baixa;
    }

    public String getCanal_pci() {
        return canal_pci;
    }

    public void setCanal_pci(String canal_pci) {
        this.canal_pci = canal_pci;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getUrl_retorn() {
        return url_retorn;
    }

    public void setUrl_retorn(String url_retorn) {
        this.url_retorn = url_retorn;
    }

    public int getTimeout_3d() {
        return timeout_3d;
    }

    public void setTimeout_3d(int timeout_3d) {
        this.timeout_3d = timeout_3d;
    }

    public String getReintent_3d_error() {
        return reintent_3d_error;
    }

    public void setReintent_3d_error(String reintent_3d_error) {
        this.reintent_3d_error = reintent_3d_error;
    }

    public String getUrl_notificacio() {
        return url_notificacio;
    }

    public void setUrl_notificacio(String url_notificacio) {
        this.url_notificacio = url_notificacio;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "canal {codi_canal=" + codi_canal + ", nom=" + nom + ", id_banc=" + id_banc + ", auto_revisio="
                + auto_revisio + ", data_alta=" + data_alta + ", data_modificacio=" + data_modificacio + ", data_baixa="
                + data_baixa + ", id_extern=" + id_extern + ", actiu=" + actiu + ", email_responsable="
                + email_responsable + ", usr_alta=" + usr_alta + ", usr_modificacio=" + usr_modificacio + ", usr_baixa="
                + usr_baixa + ", canal_pci=" + canal_pci + ", password=" + password + ", url_retorn=" + url_retorn
                + ", timeout_3d=" + timeout_3d + ", reintent_3d_error=" + reintent_3d_error + ", url_notificacio="
                + url_notificacio + "}";
    }



}
```

this is my **canalrepo.java**

```
package fcb.inetum.bo.repo;

import java.util.*;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

import fcb.inetum.bo.model.canal;

public interface canalrepo extends JpaRepository<canal,String> {

    void deleteCanalBycanal_codi(String canal_codi);

    Optional<canal> findCanalBycanal_codi(String canal_codi);

}
```

**canalservice.java**

```
package fcb.inetum.bo.service;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.UUID;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import fcb.inetum.bo.exceptions.CanalNotFoundException;
import fcb.inetum.bo.model.canal;
import fcb.inetum.bo.repo.canalrepo;

@Service
public class canalService {
    private final canalrepo canalrepo;

    @Autowired
    public canalService(canalrepo canalrepo) {
        this.canalrepo = canalrepo;

    }

    public canal AddCanal(canal canal) {
        canal.setCodi_canal(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        return canalrepo.save(canal);
    }

    public List<canal> FindAllCanal() {
        return canalrepo.findAll();
    }

    public canal UpdateCanal(canal canal) {
        return canalrepo.save(canal);
    }

    public canal findCanalBycanal_codi(String canal_codi) {
        return canalrepo.findCanalBycanal_codi(canal_codi)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new CanalNotFoundException("Canal Con codi "+canal_codi+" not found"));
    }
    public void DeleteCanal(String canal_codi) {
    canalrepo.deleteCanalBycanal_codi(canal_codi);
    
    }

}
```

**canalnotfound.java**

```
package fcb.inetum.bo.exceptions;

public class CanalNotFoundException extends RuntimeException {
    public CanalNotFoundException(String message) {

        super(message);
    }

}
```

Comment: I think CanalRepo needs an @Repository annotation. Please use the standard Java naming conventions too!

Comment: Is there a special reason why using an old version of spring boot 2.5.13 ? Current version 2.6.7 (2.7.0 is around the corner)...